# SpringBoot does not detect template of Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I started learning Thymeleaf templating with SpringBoot and my learning path was blocked by some implicit issue i could not find....

The issue is: SpringBoot app does not see template, although:

1. Controller looks like
   [image]
2. Project structure includes /templates:

[image]

3. All required dependencies are in place:

[image]

Spring Boot log:

> 2022-11-13 22:21:13.196  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> com.coffeeshop.Application               : Starting Application using
> Java 11.0.10 on LAPTOP-O6B9USVI with PID 20644
> (C:\Dev\Java\Projects\coffeeshop\build\classes\java\main started by
> User in C:\Dev\Java\Projects\coffeeshop) 2022-11-13 22:21:13.196  INFO
> 20644 --- [           main] com.coffeeshop.Application               :
> No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
> 2022-11-13 22:21:13.588  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data
> JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2022-11-13 22:21:13.604  INFO 20644
> --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 23 ms. Found 1 JPA
> repository interfaces. 2022-11-13 22:21:14.106  INFO 20644 --- [
> main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized
> with port(s): 8081 (http) 2022-11-13 22:21:14.106  INFO 20644 --- [
> main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service
> [Tomcat] 2022-11-13 22:21:14.106  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine:
> [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64] 2022-11-13 22:21:14.184  INFO 20644 --- [
> main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
> embedded WebApplicationContext 2022-11-13 22:21:14.184  INFO 20644 ---
> [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root
> WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 957 ms 2022-11-13
> 22:21:14.278  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
> PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 2022-11-13 22:21:14.309  INFO
> 20644 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    :
> HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final 2022-11-13
> 22:21:14.309  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded
> properties from resource hibernate.properties:
> {hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false,
> hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false} 2022-11-13
> 22:21:14.404  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate
> Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final} 2022-11-13 22:21:14.466  INFO 20644
> --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
> 2022-11-13 22:21:14.796  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2022-11-13 22:21:14.905  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start
> completed. 2022-11-13 22:21:14.921  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using
> JtaPlatform implementation:
> [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
> 2022-11-13 22:21:14.921  INFO 20644 --- [           main]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA
> EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2022-11-13
> 22:21:15.094  WARN 20644 --- [           main]
> JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is
> enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed
> during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to
> disable this warning 2022-11-13 22:21:15.298  INFO 20644 --- [
> main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on
> port(s): 8081 (http) with context path '' 2022-11-13 22:21:15.298
> INFO 20644 --- [           main] com.coffeeshop.Application
> : Started Application in 2.409 seconds (JVM running for 2.7)

When i check http://localhost:8081/home I got "home" string only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `@RestController` with `@Controller`. You cannot use `@RestController` because `@RestController` automatically adds `@ResponseBody` and Spring will only attempt to look up a view if `@ResponseBody` is not present.

Comment: Thanks for the help, seems i missed the fact that Java/Thymeleaf is server side rendering

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem

```java
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```